# Find instance of date in a link; RegEx; Python

Tags: python, regex, date

I have a huge list of links that roughly follow the next structure:

```
http://www.website.com/2016/2/25/11118290/story
http://www.website.com/authors/author
http://www.website.com/2016/1/25/11118290/story
http://www.website.com/authors/author
http://www.website.com/2015/12/15/11118290/story
http://www.website.com/authors/author
http://www.website.com/2010/01/01/11118290/story
http://www.website.com/authors/author
```

I need to get only the links that have a date included in them, i.e.:

```
http://www.website.com/YYYY/MM/DD/11118290/story
```

but the date can also be `YYYY/M/D` or `YYYY/MM/D` or `YYYY/M/DD`

I can't figure out what regular expression would extract only links with dates, but with the date format being slightly mutable.

Comment: @timgeb with a slash separating the first four from the second one-or-two, and third one-or-two.

Comment: @DominicMcDonnell I have an expression that matches any four digits: `\d{4}`

Comment: Try. (\d{4}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2})

Comment: Here is your test case. https://regex101.com/r/dP6eN8/1

Answer (score 3):

Using the standard library (dateutil) seems to work for me:

```
test_set = [
'http://www.website.com/2016/2/25/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
'http://www.website.com/2016/1/25/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
'http://www.website.com/2015/12/15/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
'http://www.website.com/2010/01/01/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/2010/1/1/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/2010/01/1/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
]

from dateutil.parser import parse
for lnk in test_set:
    dt = lnk.replace("http://www.website.com/","").split("/")
    dt_str = "-".join(dt[:3])
    try:
        parse(dt_str)
        print("Date: %s"  % lnk)
    except ValueError:
        print("Not a date: %s" % lnk)


Date: http://www.website.com/2016/2/25/11118290/story
Not a date: http://www.website.com/authors/author
Date: http://www.website.com/2016/1/25/11118290/story
Not a date: http://www.website.com/authors/author
Date: http://www.website.com/2015/12/15/11118290/story
Not a date: http://www.website.com/authors/author
Date: http://www.website.com/2010/01/01/11118290/story
Date: http://www.website.com/2010/1/1/11118290/story
Date: http://www.website.com/2010/01/1/11118290/story
Not a date: http://www.website.com/authors/author
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're happy with going with something simple (i.e. invalid dates *will* be matched with this), then try:

```
/(\d{4}/\d{1,2}/\d{1,2})/
```

Answer (score 0):

You could come up with sth. like:

```
import re

linklist = ['http://www.website.com/2016/2/25/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
'http://www.website.com/2016/1/25/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
'http://www.website.com/2015/12/15/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author',
'http://www.website.com/2010/01/01/11118290/story',
'http://www.website.com/authors/author']

rx = re.compile(r"""
    /                           # a forward slash
    (?:20[0-2][0-9])            # 2000-2029
    /?                          # an optional forward slash
    (?:0?[1-9]|1[12])           # 01-09, 1-9 or 11-12
    /?                          # an optional forward slash again
    (?:0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])  # 01-09, 10-29, 30-31
    /                           # followed by a forward slash
""", re.VERBOSE)
for link in linklist:
    if rx.search(link):
        print "Found: " + link
```

See [a demo on regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/rY2nU5/3) as well as on [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/m4tVi8).
The number ranges limit the numbers to real dates (e.g. `2016/13/31` would not be considered valid).